# Global Resources translation doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, app-globalresources

I am trying to implemented App_GlobalResources for my application to support multi-language.

I've created an `AppGlobalResources` folder, inside two files:

```
WebResources.resx
WebResources.de.resx
```

In each one, I put a `TestString` name which equals to 'test' in the default one and 'German' in the `de` one.

In the Page_Load I put the following:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de");
```

When I call:

```
txtTest.Text = WebResources.TestString;
```

I get the default text 'test' and not 'German' as it supposes to.

The file properties for both resx files are:

```
Build Action: Embedded Resource
Custom Tool: PublicResXFileCodeGenerator
```

**Update:**

I checked the WebResources.de.designer.cs and it's empty, unlike the WebResources.Deisgner.cs which has code generated for it.

Developing a .NET 4.6.1 web project using Visual Studio Community edition 2017.

Comment: Have you tried using the string "de-DE"?

Comment: @ste-fu yes, same issue. BTW I checked that designer.cs file and for the de, nothing is generated, whether for the default it is.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the second resx file didn't have the right build action and custom tool set. Once I changed it, it works.